# how to repeat values of B variable till number of A variables are finished

Tags: bash, shell-script, programming

I have infile with values for 2 variables

```
# cat infile
A 1
B 2
C
D
E
```

I want to read variable a & b, so that if $b has null value, it should repeat like 1..2,
till all $a values are read.

so if I use a loop that does `echo $a $b`

```
# cat loop.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cat infile | while
  read a b
do
  echo $a $b
done
```

result is somewhat same as infile.

But I want an if statement that should repeat $b, so that it should echo

```
A 1
B 2
C 1
D 2
E 1
```

Comment: It is not quite clear, could you add more details on how the output is arrived at? or more examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that once the second column runs out of values, there will be no further values in that column,

```bsh
awk '{ if ($2 == "") $2 = saved[(i++)%n]; else saved[n++] = $2 }; 1' file
```

This reads the values of the second column into the `saved` array with index `0` holding the first value and incrementing `n` each time.  When the second column runs out of values, this array is used to populate the column in a cyclic fashion, using `i` as a counter and folding its value back to zero at multiples of `n` using the modulus operator.

Testing:

```
$ cat file
A 1
B 2
C
D
E
```

```
$ awk '{ if ($2 == "") $2 = saved[(i++)%n]; else saved[n++] = $2 }; 1' file
A 1
B 2
C 1
D 2
E 1
```

```
$ cat otherfile
A apple
B bumblebee
C sunshine
D
E
F
G
H
```

```
$ awk '{ if ($2 == "") $2 = saved[(i++)%n]; else saved[n++] = $2 }; 1' otherfile
A apple
B bumblebee
C sunshine
D apple
E bumblebee
F sunshine
G apple
H bumblebee
```